# mxGraph: How to position edge labels a the bottom

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm using the mxGraph library to render some diagrams, can someone help me to position the edge labels at the bottom instead of the middle?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In a stylesheet for relevant edges do

```
<add as="verticalAlign" value="top" />
<add as="verticalLabelPosition" value="bottom" />
```

Or do it inline when inserting an edge

```
graph.insertEdge(..., 'defaultEdge;verticalAlign=top;verticalLabelPosition=bottom');
```

"defaultEdge" is there to keep the rest of default styles, not override them completely.

This positions label bounds on the bottom of an edge, and positions labels at the top of their bounds.

Comment: Suppose I have this: **<mxCell id="3_4" customId="3_4" value="3-4" edge="1" parent="1" source="3" target="4">
    <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
</mxCell>**, Do I add the lines you refered within the mxGeometry node?

Comment: No, if you're editing the model via XML then you need to add the `style="defaultEdge;verticalAlign=top;verticalLabelPosition=bottom"` attribute to `mxCell` elements. Further reading: https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual.html#3.1.3.1 Programmatic stylesheet example: https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/stylesheet.html

Comment: Works perfectly for me with mxGraph 3.7.5. Without a reproducer of your problem in code (preferably [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) it's impossible to tell, why it doesn't work for you.