# mxGraph's HIerarchicalLayout: Edges and labels cross

Tags: mxgraph

I'm using the `mxHierarchicalLayout` to render my diagram. Unfortunately, it seems that labels by default cross the edges. Is there any possibility to tell the layout or the graph to place the labels aside an edge?

Would be great if one could make the layout aware of the labels, since just rendering the labels aside an edge wouldn't solve the issue in all cases. It might happen that some edge segments are horizontal. This could result in a horizontal segment crossing another vertical edge and overlapping labels.

Here is [a JFiddle demonstrating this](https://jsfiddle.net/mh6gtLnu/1/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mxGraph: How to position edge labels a the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159545/mxgraph-how-to-position-edge-labels-a-the-bottom)